# How can I remove opacity, visibility and transition form Redux framework "Typography Fields"?

Tags: css, wordpress, typography, redux-framework

How can I remove this code of CSS without editing redux core files?

```
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
```

When I add Typography fields to a selector, these codes are added to Auto. What are the above code types in the typography field necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are reporting occurs because you have acync_typography set to true. It's expected behaviour. The alternative is to set that argument to false.